# Using Hunspell with Python for spelling cannot handle Portuguese word with sign

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, spacy, hunspell

I am trying to correct typos, and for this, I am using Spacy with Hunspell and Python. I wrote the following code to find suggested words for "cardaço" which is an wrong way to write "cadarço" in Portuguese.

```
import hunspell
from spacy.tokens import Token
import spacy

class spaCyHunSpell(object):
    name = 'spacy_hunspell'

    def __init__(self, dic_path, aff_path):
        self.hobj = hunspell.HunSpell(dic_path, aff_path)
        Token.set_extension('hunspell_spell', default=None)
        Token.set_extension('hunspell_suggest', getter=self.get_suggestion)

    def __call__(self, doc):
        for token in doc:
            token._.hunspell_spell = self.hobj.spell(token.text)
        return doc

    def get_suggestion(self, token):
        return self.hobj.suggest(token.text)

nlp = spacy.load('pt')
hunspell = spaCyHunSpell('/usr/share/hunspell/pt_BR.dic',     '/usr/share/hunspell/pt_BR.aff')
nlp.add_pipe(hunspell)
doc = nlp(u'cardaço')
print(doc[0]._.hunspell_suggest)
```

I have all libraries installed correctly and the code above works fine for the word "feninine" for example. My problem is the "ç".

The error I get is:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe7 in position 5: invalid continuation byte

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/netshoes/PycharmProjects/migracao-sas/modelo_NICHO2/main.py", line 29, in <module>
    print(doc[0]._.hunspell_suggest)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/spacy/tokens/underscore.py", line 31, in __getattr__
    return getter(self._obj)
  File "/home/netshoes/PycharmProjects/migracao-sas/modelo_NICHO2/main.py", line 23, in get_suggestion
    return self.hobj.suggest(token.text)
SystemError: <built-in method suggest of HunSpell object at 0x7f6b3560fe50> returned a result with an error set
```

I tried to use use unidecode without success.

My Python version is 3.6

Comment: Your input isn't Unicode. See the [Stack Overflow `character-encording` tag info](/tags/character-encoding/info) for troubleshooting tips.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put this code in first line of the file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a note if anyone's stucks with this. There is a package called [spacy_hunspell](https://github.com/tokestermw/spacy_hunspell) that is a wrapper around Hunspell for Python and spaCy. It uses the Hunspell python version `0.5.0`, which comes with encoding problems just like the one in this thread, mentioned [here](https://github.com/blatinier/pyhunspell/issues/32).

To solve this, just change the [setup.py](https://github.com/tokestermw/spacy_hunspell/blob/master/setup.py) file of the spacy_hunspell to `hunspell==0.5.5`, and the issue is solved.